# Can mod_security run in a “permissive” mode?

Tags: apache, mod-security

SELinux has a "permissive" mode where violations are logged but not enforced, thus allowing for debugging and troubleshooting before locking the system down.

Is there such a feature in Apache mod_security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `SecRuleEngine` directive set to `DetectionOnly` should help. There will be no disruptive actions like blocking. This directive should help you debug/analyze rules before going live on production.

Ref: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#SecRuleEngine

The directive is present in version 3 as well.